# Does Tomcat (external not server runtime) work with JDK 11

Tags: java, tomcat, exception

Tomcat:

- server.info=3DApache Tomcat/8.5.8
- server.number=3D8.5.8.0
- server.built=3DNov 3 2016 21:14:13 UTC
- OS: Windows 10
- Eclipse: 2018-12-R

I get an Unsupported-Operation-Exception Boot class path mechanism is not supported.

Few lines from stack trace:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Boot class path mechanism is not supported 
  at java.management/sun.management.RuntimeImpl.getBootClassPath(RuntimeImpl.java:99) 
  at xxx.service.IMDiagnostics.getStartupEnv(IMDiagnostics.java:520) 
  at
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Dont put additional information into comments, always edit your question instead. .

Comment: According to http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html, Tomcat 8 should work with Java 11 8.5.8 is probably simply too old (I think that was released long before Java 11) you should try the current version which is 8.5.38

Answer (score 4):

As per migration guide from Oracle Java docs, **Apache Tomcat is actively being tested for Java 11+ support**. At high level, its good combination to use Tomcat 9 with Java 11. Not Tomcat 8 as indicated by GhostCat as well.

Please review below URL for periodic updates.
https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/quality/Quality+Outreach

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, there seems to be no official document that specifies the version of Java that Tomcat officially supports.

But then: Tomcat 8 is based (built) for Java 7, whereas there are various links out there where people discuss using Tomcat **9** with Java 11.

My conclusion: Tomcat 8 and Java 11 are probably a no-go, and you shouldn't invest your time trying to get it to work.

Comment: I agree that a official document/announcement which clearly states tomcat version and JDK/JRE version(9/10/11) support must exist.

Comment: this activity is part of a big effort. I shall try it out and let you know when I re-visit it. Hence I am treating all the responses as possible efforts which I shall execute in upcoming sprints. Needless to say thank you very much.

Comment: @mupgda You are welcome. In case you find one of the answer to really "answer" your question, consider accepting that answer at some point.

Comment: You can find that official documentation at [*Apache Tomcat Versions*](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html).