# Resource annotations in Servlets are only working with Java 8, not with Java 11 on a Tomcat 8 server

Tags: java, servlets, annotations, tomcat8

I have developed a HTTP servlet that implements MessageListener and connects to a JMS-based MQ system using javax.jms.ConnectionFactoy.

The connection factory is injected to the servlet via a Resource annotation.

```
@Resource(name = "jms/ConnectionFactory")
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```

The resource is defined in the context.xml configuration file.

What I have experienced is that when I compile the servlet using Java 11, the javax.annotation.Ressource is simply ignored, while I can still lookup the resource based on its name in the context directly.
But, when I compile it using Java 8, the resource is injected to the annotated field in the servlet.

Can someone explain this?

Another point is that the javax namespace is replaced by the jakarate one, when migrating from Java EE to Jakarta EE. Most of the JMS library are still implemented using the javax.jms.* interfaces, like ConnectionFactory, Queue, etc.

Does anyone has experience how compatibility looks like or is a reimplementation of JMS libs necessary?

Comment: Use Tomcat 9 with Java 11, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861840/does-tomcat-external-not-server-runtime-work-with-jdk-11

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@Resource annotation doesn't work in Tomact 10.0.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69249988/resource-annotation-doesnt-work-in-tomact-10-0-10)

Comment: Remark: though the question specifically targets `jakarta.annotation.*` on Tomcat 10 and any Java version, it also applies to `javax.annotation.*` and Java versions 11 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

For Java 11 deployment, use Tomcat 10.1.x, Jakarta EE package naming, Servlet 6 API, and Jakarta Messaging 3.1 API.

Earlier versions may run on Java 11 too, but these versions are built specifically for Java 11 as a minimum requirement.

This combination will likely work on Java 17 as well as Java 11. Java 17 is the latest Long-Term Support (LTS) version. While support is not officially required in Jakarta EE, the various teams seem to be aiming for their latest versions to run well on Java 17.

## Use Tomcat Version 10.1 for Java 11

According to [*Apache Tomcat Versions*](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html), Version 10.1 of Tomcat supports Java 11 while versions 9 and 10.0 are aimed at Java 8.

### Package name

You will need to change your `import` statements from `javax.*`package to `jakarta.*`. This change in package naming is due to the transition from Oracle to the Eclipse Foundation as the stewards of [Jakarta EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE) technology (formerly Java EE).

#### Servlet API

Switch to the appropriate version of the Servlet API, version 6. See [Servlet specifications page](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/).

#### Messaging API

Note that JMS has become [Jakarta Messaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Messaging). You’ll need to adjust your `import` statements and version number accordingly. See [specifications page](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/messaging/).

Likewise, update your Jakarta Messaging implementation.

Comment: Tomcat versions support _"any stable Java release that meets the requirements "_. This means that the OP can safely use Tomcat 9 with Java 11 until his favorite JMS implementations switches to JMS 3.0.